# using startMonitoringVisits to monitor region

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, cllocationmanager, clregion

Class reference is not explaining WHEN to use it or what exactly it is doing. i need to monitor a region exits the fact that `startMonitoringForRegion:` is not 100% reliable is a problem.

Can `startMonitoringVisits` help me here? if not - any other ideas on how to fix this problem? (like significant distance AND monitoring region?)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

startMonitoringVisits gives you access to visits detected by iOS. To get an idea of what these visits are open Settings app, tap Privacy >> Location Services >> System Services >> Frequent Locations

Apple does not elaborate on what exactly qualified as a visit. But no matter what they are, the visits are not related to region monitoring events. And they are not real time - all visit events will be delayed, in my experience the delay is within 5 to 60 minutes range.

So the answer is: startMonitoringVisits will not help you to monitor regions.

Comment: It doesn't sounds right - what you say is -
Apple monitoring the user frequent visited locations - not the app.
The app can only track when the device enters a "visited" region?
If yes - how do i know what is this place to offer something to the user? and what can i do with this info if i dont know the logic behind the creation of a "visit"?

Comment: iOS can monitor visits, see CLVisit for a definition of visit. Starting with version 8 iOS can share collected visit info with an app. These visits are absolutely unrelated to region monitoring. How to use visit info, is up to you. I found visits info extremely valuable for my use case. Your mileage may vary. But again: your question was about using startMonitoringVisits to improve region monitoring quality. The answer is no, it will not help. I am sorry it doesn't sound right to you.